Trace and Span IDs not showing in Spring Boot logs but visible in Grafana via OpenTelemetry
I am using Spring Boot 3.4.0 with OpenTelemetry Spring Starter for tracing and logging. I am exporting the logs using the OpenTelemetry collector to Loki, and the traces and spans are visible in Grafana. However, I am unable to see the trace_id and span_id in the console logs.
I tried adding the following property to my application.properties file:
logging.pattern.level=trace_id=%mdc{trace_id} span_id=%mdc{span_id} trace_flags=%mdc{trace_flags} %5p

But the trace and span IDs are still not being mapped in the console logs.
Is there something I am missing in my configuration?
Do I need to enable additional configurations for MDC in Spring Boot or OpenTelemetry?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

I resolved the issue by adding the following dependency to my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
</dependency>

